# FTPSHook Airflow (522 SSL/TLS required on the data channel)

Tags: python, ssl, ftp, airflow, ftplib

I'm trying to use FTPSHook to send file through FTP TLS/SSL Explicit Encryption. Here's my code

```
remote_filepath=pathfile
local_filepath=pathfile2
hook = FTPSHook(ftp_conn_id='ftp_test')
hook.store_file(remote_filepath, local_filepath)
```

and I'm getting this error when I run the DAG:

> 522 SSL/TLS required on the data channel

Does anyone ever done this before? How can I secure the connection with `FTPSHook`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ftplib (the underlying implementation of FTP(S) for the `FTPSHook`) does not encrypt the FTP data connection by default. To enable it, you have to call [`FTP_TLS.prot_p()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP_TLS.prot_p). With `FTPSHook` API, you do it like this:

```
hook = FTPSHook(ftp_conn_id='ftp_test')
hook.get_conn().prot_p()
```